# Custom x-axes for several charts in Matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I need to mark the minimum and maximum value of the graph. My code marks them on only one of all the graphs.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as my_graph
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
def several_tag(tags):
    mmin=[]
    mmax=[]
    current_db=r.hget('db_id', 'value')
    data=db_arch[current_db]

    for counter, ctag in enumerate(tags):
        vals=[]
        times=[]
        tag_values=data.find({'tagname':ctag},{'value':1,'time':1,'_id':0})
        for tag in tag_values:
            try:
                vals.append(round(float(tag['value']),2))
            except:
                vals.append(0)
            times.append(datetime.fromtimestamp(tag['time']))

        mmin.append(min(vals))
        mmax.append(max(vals))
        my_graph.ylim(min(mmin)-5,max(mmax)+5)

        my_graph.plot(times, vals)


        def paint_x(vals):
            my_graph.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%H:%M:%S"))
            locator=mdates.ticker.FixedLocator([mdates.date2num(times[vals.index(min(vals))]),mdates.date2num(times[vals.index(max(vals))])])
            my_graph.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)

        paint_x(vals)

        my_graph.xticks(size="xx-small", color="gray")

        my_graph.annotate('max: %s' % max(vals), size="x-small", color="red", xy=(mdates.date2num(times[vals.index(max(vals))]), max(vals)), xycoords='data', xytext=(10, 10), textcoords='offset points', arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='-|>'))
        my_graph.annotate('min: %s' % min(vals), size="x-small", color=(0.4, 0.5, 0.3), xy=(mdates.date2num(times[vals.index(min(vals))]), min(vals)), xycoords='data', xytext=(15, -15), textcoords='offset points', arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='-|>'))

        my_graph.grid(True)

    my_graph.savefig(r'1.png', transparent=True)


several_tag(['MKA50GE004ZQ_V', 'MKA50GE003ZQ_V'])
```

Result: http://rghost.net/48775269.view

How to get a mark of extreme values ​​on the timeline for all charts?

Comment: It looks from your included image that all the plots have the required minima/maxima. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @GregHow to get a mark of extreme values ​​on the timeline for all charts?

Comment: What do you mean by charts, the plots you have shown already have the minimum and maximum marked, what more is it that you want? Please give more details or people can't understand what it is you are asking.